# Gradle compile dependency ordering in InteliJ

Tags: java, servlets, ide, intellij-idea

I have a gradle project with subprojects, and Servlet API 2.5.  I've added Servlet 3.0 and compile fine from command line gradle.  However, InteliJ loads Servlet 2.5 classes first, so I am unable to compile.

How can I manage dependency ordering within InteliJ?

Comment: Check this https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/synchronizing-changes-in-gradle-project-and-intellij-idea-project.html#d91974e346

Comment: @Karthikeyan - Thanks.  I had looked at that.  It says "Modify module dependencies as required: for example, remove or add dependencies." ... I don't want to delete 2.5, I want to move it after 3.0.  And there is no support for order, just CRUD.

Answer (score 1):

It's there, you might have missed it:

In IntelliJ go to:
File -> Project Structure -> Modules (on the left) -> Dependencies (tab on the right)

Now you can move the order of the dependencies up and down using the arrow buttons on the right. This should get the class loader order right for compilation.

I'm not sure why you would leave both jars in there though, so you might want to delete one of them. Also make sure the scope is "provided" and the export button is unchecked for both of them (assuming you're creating a war file).

We've found we frequently need to go through all 3 places that IntelliJ lists the libraries and clean up old jar files on every change to build.gradle. We also need to frequently delete out the multiple lib directories in our projects 'out' or 'build' dirs to get rid of old jars that IntelliJ seems incapable of cleaning up itself. The IntelliJ integration with Gradle is so abysmal we're considering either going back to Eclipse/STS or going back to Maven! So sad.

http://java.dzone.com/articles/hell-intellij-and-gradle